# The state in the reducer is initialized to a nested object

Tags: react-redux

The state is set to nested object {profile: {profile: {}} instead of {profile: {}}. And then the store also has this nested object.

```html
const profile = {
    nickname: '',
    avatar: '',
};

export default (state = {profile}, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_PROFILE':
        return  {
          ...state,
          profile: action.payload
        };

        default:
            return state;

  }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the default state? if not can you please show what is in the action.payload

Comment: The action.payload is exactly as expected the object {profile: {...}} (the ... = nickname: 'Dany', avatar: 'somepath.jpg'}
But insted of replacing the profile object in the store, it adds it as a child to it.
So in the store I have {profile: {profile: {}}

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in the comment that action.payload will be {profile: {...}}.

This is what you are trying to do `profile: {profile: {...}}`

So one thing what you can do is this `profile: action.payload.profile` it should solve your problem.

Or while dispatching the action GET_PROFILE you can send {the ... = nickname: 'Dany', avatar: 'somepath.jpg'} as data instead of {people: {the ... = nickname: 'Dany', avatar: 'somepath.jpg'}}. So this way you can keep **action.payload** in the reducer.

Comment: This is what I do.
I send just the profile object like that {nickname: ...}